# Interpretation of confidence interval using geom_smooth in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression, data-visualization, confidence-interval

I plotted data from two groups using `geom_smooth` in `ggplot2`. The default method `loess` was used for the lines and confidence interval was also added. Am I right by assuming if the lines and confidence intervals do not overlap there is a significant difference? For example, in the following graph, is it correct that there is significant difference between the two groups at age 3, 4 but not 5, 2nd grade and 4th grade?
[image: two group graph]

Comment: Not necessarily: references: https://cscu.cornell.edu/wp-content/uploads/73_ci.pdf. https://towardsdatascience.com/why-overlapping-confidence-intervals-mean-nothing-about-statistical-significance-48360559900a. https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82702323.pdf.  BTW, this question might be more appropriate for the Cross Validated site; this isn't a programming question within typical Stack Overflow guidelines.